# RGB Analog Video Capture

Tags: video, video-adapters, video-capture

I am looking for a video capture device that can successfully capture 240 & 480 (p and i) signals properly.  I am not worried about LAG too much because I will be splitting signals to production monitors.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.  It really does seem 240 and 480 are going out the window and almost no capture devices support them anymore.

Comment: How are you receiving this video signal?

Comment: SCART Connector that I can break out into RGB or any other type of Analog Standard.  Retro Gaming Systems

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using two devices. One which is a self-contained device:

- [Composite, S-Video, and HDMI to HDMI Converter and Switch with HDMI PAL NTSC Support - Monoprice.com](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=9994)

and the other which is a video capture card:

- [Diamond MM VC500 Video Capture Card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815306013)

**References**

- [240p — HD Retrovision](https://www.hdretrovision.com/240p/)
- [How to get the best picture from your Retro games](https://draculascave.co/2014/12/18/the-ultimate-cable-guide-how-to-get-the-best-picture-from-your-retro-games/)